# python program to return exit code 0 if passes and 1 if fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-code

I have a text file that includes a word like "test". Now what i am trying to do is using python i am opening that text file and search for that word. If the word exists then the python program should return exit code 0 or else 1.

This is the code that i have written that returns 0 or 1.

```
word = "test"

def check():
    with open("tex.txt", "r") as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):  
            if word in line:

                return 0
            else:
                return 1

print(check())
```

```
output

0
```

what I want is I want to store this exit code in some variable so that i can pass this to a yaml file. Can someone guide me here how can i store this exit code in a variable? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure your code is indented properly? The way it appears here, it will always return 1 unless the word is in the first line

Comment: This program does not what is written in the descripition. `return 0` immediately when the word is found in a line, but `return 1` only at the end when the whole file has been read without finding the word.

Comment: yes i want to return 1 if the text is not found in the whole file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), but since you edited your question, I am not sure anymore. Try this:

```
import sys

word = "test"

def check():
    with open("tex.txt", "r") as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):  
            if word in line:
                return 0
     
    return 1

is_word_found = check() # store the return value of check() in variable `is_word_found`
print(is_word_found) # prints value of `is_word_found` to standard output
sys.exit(is_word_found) # exit the program with status code `is_word_found`
```

BTW: as @gimix and @VPfB mentioned, your `check()` function did return a value immediately after it checked the first line of your file. I included a fix for that, now 1 is returned only if the word is not found is any line of your file.

Comment: how can i see the output?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: I want to save the return value in some variable for example a = output and then want to print the variable a